# Unable to remove a ppa

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa

I had recently added the stormcloud ppa (`ppa:jolicloud-team/ppa`) to my software sources - but it happens to be an empty source and whenever I try to install stormcloud or update my system it gives an error. For example:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am unable to remove this ppa - I cannot located it in /etc/apt/sources.list, nor can I remote it from the command line. For example, when I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:cooperjona/stormcloud
```

It gives the following error.

```
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~cooperjona/+archive/stormcloud) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

When I used ppa-purge, I got the following - as a result of which I aborted.

`$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:jolicloud-team/ppa`

```
Updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: jolicloud-team ppa
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
Package revert list generated:
 awesome/precise jolicloud-daemon/precise jolicloud-desktop-environment/precise 
jupiter/precise lua-lgi/precise nickel-browser/precise 
nickel-browser-l10n/precise nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-extra/precise 
nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree/precise xsettingsd/precise

Disabling jolicloud-team PPA from 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jolicloud-team-ppa-precise.list
Updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Release 'precise' for 'jolicloud-daemon' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'jolicloud-desktop-environment' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'jupiter' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'nickel-browser' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'nickel-browser-l10n' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-extra' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree' was not found
E: Release 'precise' for 'xsettingsd' was not found
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "jolicloud-daemon"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "jolicloud-desktop-environment"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "jupiter"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-browser"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-browser-l10n"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-extra"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "xsettingsd"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "jolicloud-daemon"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "jolicloud-desktop-environment"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "jupiter"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-browser"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-browser-l10n"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-extra"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "nickel-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree"
Unable to find an archive "precise" for the package "xsettingsd"
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  awesome 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libev4{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  feh{u} giblib1{u} libjpeg-progs{u} libjpeg-turbo-progs{u} lua-lgi{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 5 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 873 kB of archives. After unpacking 575 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jolicloud-desktop-environment : Depends: awesome (>= 3.5) but 3.4.11-1ubuntu1 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages: 
1)     jolicloud-desktop-environment



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:                  
1)     awesome [3.5-rc1-8~precise1 (now)]                                   
2)     feh [2.2-1 (now, precise)]                                           
3)     giblib1 [1.2.4-8 (now, precise)]                                     
4)     libjpeg-turbo-progs [1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1 (now, precise-updates)]
5)     lua-lgi [0.6.2-1ubuntu1~precise1 (now)]                              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
```

It's not harming my computer or something, but based on my past experiences, I've learnt a lesson or two regarding faulty ppas, and I don't want a complete breakdown of my packages. What should I do?

(I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that if you enter the folllowing command in Terminal you can remove them from there.

```
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=2
```

or System Settings> Software and Updates. Next click on the 2nd tab to get to Other Software.

Select the source you do not want to check (the empty one) and either turn off the tick or remove it all together.

Comment: Ah, I managed to do with Software Center - something along the lines of what you said. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer helped, perhaps you could up-vote it or even, if you are feeling generous, mark it a the answer you chose with a green tick :)